# Value of ModalPicker cannot pass to Form

Tags: android, ios, forms, react-native, picker

I am writing a picker to select genders inside a series of Forms on React-native, but the selected value couldn't pass to the Form. What's the problem? Here is my code.

```
      <Form style={styles.orderContainer} ref="form">
        <View style={styles.orderInputContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.orderInputText}>Name</Text>
          <TextInput defaultValue={data.username} type="TextInput" name="name" style={styles.orderInput} ref="username" returnKeyType={"next"} autoFocus={true} autoCapitalize="none" autoCorrect={false} placeholder="Please enter your name" clearButtonMode='while-editing' blurOnSubmit={false} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.orderInputContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.orderInputText}>Gender</Text>
          <ModalPicker
            data={genderA} 
            type="ModalPicker"
            onChange={(option)=>{ this.setState({genders:option.label})}}>
            <TextInput  
              editable={false}
              defaultValue={data.gender}
              type="TextInput" name="gender" style={styles.orderInput} ref="gender" 
              value={this.state.genders} />
          </ModalPicker>
        </View>
      </Form>
```